# How to find all serial devices (ttyS, ttyUSB, ..) on Linux without opening them?

Tags: linux, serial-port

What is the proper way to get a list of all available serial ports/devices on a Linux system?

In other words, when I iterate over all devices in `/dev/`, how do I tell which ones are serial ports in the classic way, that is, those usually supporting baud rates and [RTS/CTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#RTS.2FCTS_handshaking) flow control?

The solution would be coded in C.

I ask because I am using a third-party library that does this clearly wrong: It appears to only iterate over `/dev/ttyS*`. The problem is that there are, for instance, serial ports over USB (provided by USB-RS232 adapters), and those are listed under /dev/ttyUSB*. And reading the [Serial-HOWTO at Linux.org](http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/Serial-HOWTO.html), I get the idea that there'll be other name spaces as well, as time comes.

So I need to find the official way to detect serial devices. The problem is that none appears to be documented, or I can't find it.

I imagine one way would be to open all files from `/dev/tty*` and call a specific `ioctl()` on them that is only available on serial devices. Would that be a good solution, though?

#### Update

*hrickards* suggested to look at the source for "setserial".
Its code does exactly what I had in mind:

First, it opens a device with:

```
fd = open (path, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK)
```

Then it invokes:

```
ioctl (fd, TIOCGSERIAL, &serinfo)
```

If that call returns no error, then it's a serial device, apparently.

I found similar code in *[Serial Programming/termios](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming:Unix/termios)*, which suggested to also add the `O_NOCTTY` option.

**There is one problem with this approach, though:**

When I tested this code on BSD Unix (that is, Mac OS X), it worked as well. ***However***, serial devices that are provided through Bluetooth cause the system (driver) to try to connect to the Bluetooth device, which takes a while before it'll return with a timeout error. This is caused by just opening the device. And I can imagine that similar things can happen on Linux as well - ideally, I should not need to open the device to figure out its type. I wonder if there's also a way to invoke `ioctl` functions without an open, or open a device in a way that it does not cause connections to be made?

What should I do?

Comment: Someone anonymous had suggested this edit, which was rejected, so I leave it here as a comment instead:  If you use the TIOCGSERIAL flag in the ioctl call, instead of TIOCMGET, then the call do not return error with some wrong paths that do not refer to a COM (serial) port. With TIOCMGET flag, ioctl works only with the COM ports available to access in both TTY and TTYUSB possible paths.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The `/sys` filesystem should contain plenty information for your quest. My system (2.6.32-40-generic #87-Ubuntu) suggests:

```
/sys/class/tty
```

Which gives you descriptions of all TTY devices known to the system. A trimmed down example:

```
# ll /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-03-28 20:43 /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-03-28 20:44 /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1/
```

Following one of these links:

```
# ll /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0/
insgesamt 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 2012-03-28 20:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 2012-03-28 20:43 ../
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2012-03-28 20:49 dev
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 2012-03-28 20:43 device -> ../../../ttyUSB0/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 2012-03-28 20:49 power/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 2012-03-28 20:43 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../../../../class/tty/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2012-03-28 20:43 uevent
```

Here the `dev` file contains this information:

```
# cat /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0/dev
188:0
```

This is the major/minor node. These can be searched in the `/dev` directory to get user-friendly names:

```
# ll -R /dev |grep "188, *0"
crw-rw----   1 root dialout 188,   0 2012-03-28 20:44 ttyUSB0
```

The `/sys/class/tty` dir contains all TTY devices but you might want to exclude those pesky virtual terminals and pseudo terminals. I suggest you examine only those which have a `device/driver` entry:

```
# ll /sys/class/tty/*/device/driver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-03-28 19:07 /sys/class/tty/ttyS0/device/driver -> ../../../bus/pnp/drivers/serial/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-03-28 19:07 /sys/class/tty/ttyS1/device/driver -> ../../../bus/pnp/drivers/serial/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-03-28 19:07 /sys/class/tty/ttyS2/device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/serial8250/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-03-28 19:07 /sys/class/tty/ttyS3/device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/serial8250/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-03-28 20:43 /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0/device/driver -> ../../../../../../../../bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-03-28 21:15 /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB1/device/driver -> ../../../../../../../../bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/
```

Comment: @entalpi You'll find `/dev/zero` . Do you really think, this is a serial device?

Comment: Searching in /dev is useless, since you already have the name in /sys/class/tty (as by default udev creates the /dev/DEVNAME node). What you are interested about is any "symbolic" link in /dev that points to such device. This is much much harder to find.

Answer (score 38):

In recent kernels (not sure since when) you can list the contents of /dev/serial to get a list of the serial ports on your system. They are actually symlinks pointing to the correct /dev/ node:

```
flu0@laptop:~$ ls /dev/serial/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 60 2011-07-20 17:12 by-id/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 60 2011-07-20 17:12 by-path/
flu0@laptop:~$ ls /dev/serial/by-id/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 2011-07-20 17:12 usb-Prolific_Technology_Inc._USB-Serial_Controller-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
flu0@laptop:~$ ls /dev/serial/by-path/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 2011-07-20 17:12 pci-0000:00:0b.0-usb-0:3:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
```

This is a USB-Serial adapter, as you can see. Note that when there are no serial ports on the system, the /dev/serial/ directory does not exists. Hope this helps :).

Comment: This is a function of udev (specifically its configuration in /lib/udev/rules.d/??-persistent-serial.rules), which was introduced in 2.5.

Comment: Great tip! Unfortunately I don't think this will show built in serial ports,  only USB serial ports (seen by udev when attached).   I don't see anything for /dev/serial in Ubuntu 14 in a VMware VM (with ttyS0/COM1 supplied by the VM), and the udev rules (60-persistent-serial.rules) are looking only at udev devices -- I don't think udev finds out about the "built-in" ttyS* serial ports, they'll have to be tested with ioctl or similar as in the other answers.

Comment: ls /dev/serial/
ls: cannot access '/dev/serial/': No such file or directory
Slackware 14.2 current x64

Comment: @jpka: That happens if there's no serial device to find. I did as above and it worked. I then unplugged my (FTDI) serial device from the USB and afterwards it produced the error that you described.

Answer (score 26):

I found

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

doing the job.

Comment: This gives only the actual serial ports. Not USB-RS232, etc. as OP asks for.

Comment: Handy for finding the Arduino serial port

Answer (score 19):

I'm doing something like the following code. It works for USB-devices and also the stupid serial8250-devuices that we all have 30 of - but only a couple of them realy works.

Basically I use concept from previous answers. First enumerate all tty-devices in /sys/class/tty/. Devices that does not contain a /device subdir is filtered away. /sys/class/tty/console is such a device. Then the devices actually containing a devices in then accepted as valid serial-port depending on the target of the driver-symlink fx.

```
$ ls -al /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0//device/driver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 sep  6 21:28 /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0//device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/usbserial
```

and for ttyS0

```
$ ls -al /sys/class/tty/ttyS0//device/driver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 sep  6 21:28 /sys/class/tty/ttyS0//device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/serial8250
```

All drivers driven by serial8250 must be probes using the previously mentioned ioctl.

```
        if (ioctl(fd, TIOCGSERIAL, &serinfo)==0) {
            // If device type is no PORT_UNKNOWN we accept the port
            if (serinfo.type != PORT_UNKNOWN)
                the_port_is_valid
```

Only port reporting a valid device-type is valid.

The complete source for enumerating the serialports looks like this. Additions are welcome.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/serial.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

static string get_driver(const string& tty) {
    struct stat st;
    string devicedir = tty;

    // Append '/device' to the tty-path
    devicedir += "/device";

    // Stat the devicedir and handle it if it is a symlink
    if (lstat(devicedir.c_str(), &st)==0 && S_ISLNK(st.st_mode)) {
        char buffer[1024];
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

        // Append '/driver' and return basename of the target
        devicedir += "/driver";

        if (readlink(devicedir.c_str(), buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0)
            return basename(buffer);
    }
    return "";
}

static void register_comport( list<string>& comList, list<string>& comList8250, const string& dir) {
    // Get the driver the device is using
    string driver = get_driver(dir);

    // Skip devices without a driver
    if (driver.size() > 0) {
        string devfile = string("/dev/") + basename(dir.c_str());

        // Put serial8250-devices in a seperate list
        if (driver == "serial8250") {
            comList8250.push_back(devfile);
        } else
            comList.push_back(devfile); 
    }
}

static void probe_serial8250_comports(list<string>& comList, list<string> comList8250) {
    struct serial_struct serinfo;
    list<string>::iterator it = comList8250.begin();

    // Iterate over all serial8250-devices
    while (it != comList8250.end()) {

        // Try to open the device
        int fd = open((*it).c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK | O_NOCTTY);

        if (fd >= 0) {
            // Get serial_info
            if (ioctl(fd, TIOCGSERIAL, &serinfo)==0) {
                // If device type is no PORT_UNKNOWN we accept the port
                if (serinfo.type != PORT_UNKNOWN)
                    comList.push_back(*it);
            }
            close(fd);
        }
        it ++;
    }
}

list<string> getComList() {
    int n;
    struct dirent **namelist;
    list<string> comList;
    list<string> comList8250;
    const char* sysdir = "/sys/class/tty/";

    // Scan through /sys/class/tty - it contains all tty-devices in the system
    n = scandir(sysdir, &namelist, NULL, NULL);
    if (n < 0)
        perror("scandir");
    else {
        while (n--) {
            if (strcmp(namelist[n]->d_name,"..") && strcmp(namelist[n]->d_name,".")) {

                // Construct full absolute file path
                string devicedir = sysdir;
                devicedir += namelist[n]->d_name;

                // Register the device
                register_comport(comList, comList8250, devicedir);
            }
            free(namelist[n]);
        }
        free(namelist);
    }

    // Only non-serial8250 has been added to comList without any further testing
    // serial8250-devices must be probe to check for validity
    probe_serial8250_comports(comList, comList8250);

    // Return the lsit of detected comports
    return comList;
}


int main() {
    list<string> l = getComList();

    list<string>::iterator it = l.begin();
    while (it != l.end()) {
        cout << *it << endl;
        it++;
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Comment: Thanks to Soren for this, even we know the APIs and some idea on it but you did really good Soren, thanks again.

Answer (score 15):

I think I found the answer in my kernel source documentation:
/usr/src/linux-2.6.37-rc3/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt

```
1.7 TTY info in /proc/tty
-------------------------

Information about  the  available  and actually used tty's can be found in the
directory /proc/tty.You'll  find  entries  for drivers and line disciplines in
this directory, as shown in Table 1-11.


Table 1-11: Files in /proc/tty
..............................................................................
 File          Content                                        
 drivers       list of drivers and their usage                
 ldiscs        registered line disciplines                    
 driver/serial usage statistic and status of single tty lines 
..............................................................................

To see  which  tty's  are  currently in use, you can simply look into the file
/proc/tty/drivers:

  > cat /proc/tty/drivers 
  pty_slave            /dev/pts      136   0-255 pty:slave 
  pty_master           /dev/ptm      128   0-255 pty:master 
  pty_slave            /dev/ttyp       3   0-255 pty:slave 
  pty_master           /dev/pty        2   0-255 pty:master 
  serial               /dev/cua        5   64-67 serial:callout 
  serial               /dev/ttyS       4   64-67 serial 
  /dev/tty0            /dev/tty0       4       0 system:vtmaster 
  /dev/ptmx            /dev/ptmx       5       2 system 
  /dev/console         /dev/console    5       1 system:console 
  /dev/tty             /dev/tty        5       0 system:/dev/tty 
  unknown              /dev/tty        4    1-63 console
```

Here is a link to this file:
http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git;a=blob_plain;f=Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt;hb=e8883f8057c0f7c9950fa9f20568f37bfa62f34a

Comment: Yes, that seems to be working. However, this solution requires me to read a text file and parse it. I wonder if there's a better away, i.e. a API that lets me get these contents in a structured binary format.

Answer (score 6):

setserial with the -g option appears to do what you want and the C source is available at http://www.koders.com/c/fid39344DABD14604E70DF1B8FEA7D920A94AF78BF8.aspx.

Comment: I looked at the code and it has the flaw I explain in my question at the end as it has to open the device, which may already lead to a connection attempt - which in turn is not good. But then, maybe Linux drivers are smarter than current OSX driver when it comes to bluetooth support, as they won't open a connection right away? Who knows?
Maybe I should start a new question to clarify that specifically. If it turns out that that's fine, then I can accept your answer here as well. Hmmm...

Answer (score 5):

Using /proc/tty/drivers only indicates which tty drivers are loaded.  If you're looking for a list of the serial ports check out /dev/serial, it will have two subdirectories: by-id and by-path.

EX:

```
# find . -type l
./by-path/usb-0:1.1:1.0-port0
./by-id/usb-Prolific_Technology_Inc._USB-Serial_Controller-if00-port0
```

Thanks to this post: https://superuser.com/questions/131044/how-do-i-know-which-dev-ttys-is-my-serial-port

Comment: Apparently this is distro-dependent. I cannot find /dev/serial on my box (running Debian)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu.

Comment: raspios 32 bit buster (debian) has no /dev/serial as of the may 7, 2021 release, even though it is debian buster on the arm based raspberry pi.  /dev/serial/by-path  and  /dev/serial/by-id  are distro dependent.

Answer (score 5):

My approach via group *dialout* to get every tty with user 'dialout'
`ls -l /dev/tty* | grep 'dialout'`
to only get its folder
`ls -l /dev/tty* | grep 'dialout' | rev | cut -d " " -f1 | rev`

easy listen to the tty output e.g. when arduino serial out:
`head --lines 1 < /dev/ttyUSB0`

listen to every tty out for one line only:
`for i in $(ls -l /dev/tty* | grep 'dialout' | rev | cut -d " " -f1 | rev); do head --lines 1 < $i; done`

I really like the approach via looking for drivers:
`ll /sys/class/tty/*/device/driver`

You can pick the tty-Name now:
`ls  /sys/class/tty/*/device/driver | grep 'driver' | cut -d "/" -f 5`

Answer (score 4):

I have no serial device here to test it, but if you have python and dbus you can try it yourself.

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
hwmanager = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.Hal', '/org/freedesktop/Hal/Manager')
hwmanager_i = dbus.Interface(hwmanager, 'org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager')
print hwmanager_i.FindDeviceByCapability("serial")
```

If it fails you can search inside `hwmanager_i.GetAllDevicesWithProperties()` to see if the capability name "serial" that I just guessed has a different name.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

I do not have a USB serial device, but there must be a way to find the real ports using the HAL libraries directly:

```
====================================================================
#! /usr/bin/env bash
#
# Uses HAL to find existing serial hardware
#

for sport in $(hal-find-by-capability --capability serial) ; do
  hal-get-property --udi "${sport}" --key serial.device
done

====================================================================
```

The posted python-dbus code nor this sh script lists the bluetooth /dev/rfcomm* devices, so it is not the best solution.

Note that on other unix platforms, the serial ports are not named ttyS? and even in linux, some serial cards allow you to name the devices. Assuming a pattern in the serial devices names is wrong.

Comment: Too bad HAL was removed from Ubuntu (after 12.04), it had some nice easy to use tools.  Does anyone know if there is a replacement to the above?   But if you're on a version/distro that has HAL this looks nice.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is based on udev library and below code is based on the [example2](https://github.com/robertalks/udev-examples/blob/master/udev_example2.c):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <libudev.h>

bool enumerate_serial_ports(void)
{
    struct udev* udev;
    struct udev_enumerate* enumerate;
    struct udev_list_entry* devices, *dev_list_entry;

    /* create udev object */
    udev = udev_new();
    if (!udev) 
    {
        SPDLOG_ERROR("Cannot create udev context.");
        return false;
    }

    /* create enumerate object */
    enumerate = udev_enumerate_new(udev);
    if (!enumerate) 
    {
        SPDLOG_ERROR("Cannot create enumerate context.");

        udev_unref(udev);
        return false;
    }

    udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enumerate, "tty");
    udev_enumerate_scan_devices(enumerate);

    /* fillup device list */
    devices = udev_enumerate_get_list_entry(enumerate);
    if (!devices) 
    {
        SPDLOG_ERROR("Failed to get device list.");

        udev_enumerate_unref(enumerate);
        udev_unref(udev);
        return false;
    }

    udev_list_entry_foreach(dev_list_entry, devices) 
    {
        struct udev_device* dev = udev_device_new_from_syspath(udev, udev_list_entry_get_name(dev_list_entry));

        // filter out virtual ports
        if((udev_device_get_sysnum(dev) != NULL) && (strstr(udev_device_get_devpath(dev), "/devices/virtual/") == NULL))
        {
            SPDLOG_DEBUG("subsystem={}", udev_device_get_subsystem(dev));
            SPDLOG_DEBUG("syspath={}", udev_device_get_syspath(dev));
            SPDLOG_DEBUG("sysname={}", udev_device_get_sysname(dev));
            SPDLOG_DEBUG("sysnum={}", udev_device_get_sysnum(dev));
            SPDLOG_DEBUG("devnode={}", udev_device_get_devnode(dev));
            SPDLOG_DEBUG("-----------------------------------------");
        }    
        
        /* free dev */
        udev_device_unref(dev);
    }

    /* free enumerate */
    udev_enumerate_unref(enumerate);
    /* free udev */
    udev_unref(udev);

    return true;
}
```

And the output on a RPI4 with an USB serial adaptor:

```
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - subsystem=tty
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - syspath=/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - sysname=ttyUSB0
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - sysnum=0
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - devnode=/dev/ttyUSB0
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - -----------------------------------------
                           
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - subsystem=tty
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - syspath=/sys/devices/platform/soc/fe201000.serial/tty/ttyAMA0
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - sysname=ttyAMA0
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - sysnum=0
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - devnode=/dev/ttyAMA0
[ debug ][11:50:47.645] - -----------------------------------------
                           
[ debug ][11:50:47.646] - subsystem=tty
[ debug ][11:50:47.646] - syspath=/sys/devices/platform/soc/fe215040.serial/tty/ttyS0
[ debug ][11:50:47.646] - sysname=ttyS0
[ debug ][11:50:47.646] - sysnum=0
[ debug ][11:50:47.646] - devnode=/dev/ttyS0
[ debug ][11:50:47.646] - -----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Tested it. Enumerates all serialports in /dev/ttyS*. So also all unwanted ones

Comment: What are unwanted?

Comment: Sorry I have to explain: I only want to get a list of physical available serial ports.
On my PC this would be:
/dev/ttyS0
/dev/ttyUSB0
My fix: I filtered them by using termios getattr. If that fails, I am ignoring the port.

Comment: In my example code, I have already filtered out all virtual ports. Have you included that part? It should list only physical ones which is the case for me.

Comment: Another way to filter out unwanted devices might be to look for devices that have the `TIOCGSERIAL ` attributes such as `type`; see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-tty for the definitions of them all.

Answer (score 2):

The serial communication manager library has many API and features targeted for the task you want. If the device is a USB-UART its VID/PID can be used. If the device is BT-SPP than platform specific APIs can be used. Take a look at this project for serial port programming: https://github.com/RishiGupta12/serial-communication-manager

Answer (score 2):

```
#dmesg | grep tty
```

This command show you every port

Answer (score 1):

yes, I know, I'm too late (as always). Here is my piece of code (based on the reply of mk2). Maybe this helps someone:

```
std::vector<std::string> find_serial_ports()
{
 std::vector<std::string> ports;
    std::filesystem::path kdr_path{"/proc/tty/drivers"};
    if (std::filesystem::exists(kdr_path))
    {
        std::ifstream ifile(kdr_path.generic_string());
        std::string line;
        std::vector<std::string> prefixes;
        while (std::getline(ifile, line))
        {
            std::vector<std::string> items;
            auto it = line.find_first_not_of(' ');
            while (it != std::string::npos)
            {

                auto it2 = line.substr(it).find_first_of(' ');
                if (it2 == std::string::npos)
                {
                    items.push_back(line.substr(it));
                    break;
                }
                it2 += it;
                items.push_back(line.substr(it, it2 - it));
                it = it2 + line.substr(it2).find_first_not_of(' ');
            }
            if (items.size() >= 5)
            {
                if (items[4] == "serial" && items[0].find("serial") != std::string::npos)
                {
                    prefixes.emplace_back(items[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        ifile.close();
        for (auto& p: std::filesystem::directory_iterator("/dev"))
        {
            for (const auto& pf : prefixes)
            {
                auto dev_path = p.path().generic_string();
                if (dev_path.size() >= pf.size() && std::equal(dev_path.begin(), dev_path.begin() + pf.size(), pf.begin()))
                {
                    ports.emplace_back(dev_path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ports;
}
```

Comment: It appears your code parses what answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701610/43615 refers to. If so, would you mention that in your reply, please?

Answer (score 0):

Using setserial tool:

```
setserial -gG /dev/{ttyUSB,ttyS,ttyACM}* 2>/dev/null | grep -Ev "ttyS[0-9]+.*irq\s0\s*"
```

And if you want only the port device path on the output:

```
setserial -gG /dev/{ttyUSB,ttyS,ttyACM}* 2>/dev/null | grep -Ev "ttyS[0-9]+.*irq\s0\s*" | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Possibly this solutions are not applicable to all needs, since some USB devices can be named in another way by UDEV, so more generic but less optimal (NOT RECOMMENDED):

```
setserial -gG /dev/* 2>/dev/null | grep -Ev "ttyS[0-9]+.*irq\s0\s*" | cut -d' ' -f1
```