# How do I know which serial port to use on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I'm going to be writing a program in C which is going to open a connection over serial port, and "listen" for incoming commands, then it will take some action and report back a status.

The connection is going to be over RS232 (Serial port) and I'm trying to understand how to know which port to open.

When using windows, if I hook up my usb-serial device I see "Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM4)" show up in the device manager... but on the Linux side I don't see any changes in the `/sys/class/tty` or `/dev` area, I see `ttyS0` through `ttyS7` present all the time (I'm assuming the `S` stands for serial based on [what I've read](http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/serial.html)).

So how do I know which one to connect to?

**EDIT**
While I'm **developing** this on a OpenSUSE 12.1 box (3.1 kernel), the final program will be run on uCLinux on a board running a 2.4Linux kernel, so I'm looking for pure C solutions which will work on older kernels

FYI: the `/sys` file system as noted in the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530096/how-to-find-all-serial-devices-ttys-ttyusb-on-linux-without-opening-them) didn't exist until the 2.6 kernel and my constraints force me to stick to things available in the 2.4 kernel.

Comment: Chances are that your USB serial port adapter will show up as `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Also check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530096/) if you need a way to enumerate the serial ports.

Comment: pyserial might be of help here.

Comment: @PhilippeGauthier - That would be very unfortunate considering I won't know if the user is going to use a usb->serial cable, or a straight serial cable. :(

Comment: @goldenparrot - The target platform for this program will most likely not have python support. (uCLinux)

Comment: @PhilippeGauthier - Checked out that link, it's a good idea, but using `/sys` file system which I need to stay away from. `/sys` didn't show up until 2.6 and since I need to keep compatibility in mind with our 2.4 system, I can't use that. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `dmesg` will show you the kernel message when the module is plugged in which will give it's device name.

The `/proc` file system is like the device manager on windows - somewhere in there will be a list of tty devices

Comment: Looks like reading the dmesg will work just fine: `[  827.528859] usb 2-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0` So I can see my device on /dev/ttyUSB0, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two things that I have used: (a) look for control lines (DTR, DSR, etc) and (b) open 'all' of the ports and find out which one(s) appear to be active. In the latter case it helps if you can send a message to the serial device and have it respond; this obviously works only if the device will respond to a message.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `/proc/tty/driver/serial` - you should see an uart like `16550A` instead of `unknown` and `rx` should be > 0 for existing ports. If you must guess which port will be used, open all available ports. After that, you need to set up the port for your needs (baudrate, parity, bits etc) or try to guess the incoming baudrate etc.

Comment: And also check `/proc/tty/driver/usbserial`.