# Mono SerialPort.GetPortNames() actually connected?

Tags: c#, mono

I am trying to recive a array of all connected ports with SerialPort.GetPortNames() in Mono but it returns something like this:

(Mac but it should be the same on Linux)

```
ApfelBuch:~ janwiesemann$ mono "/Users/janwiesemann/Desktop/ports/ports/bin/Debug/ports.exe"
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
/dev/ttyp0
/dev/ttyp1
/dev/ttyp2
/dev/ttyp3
/dev/ttyp4
...
/dev/ttywc
/dev/ttywd
/dev/ttywe
/dev/ttywf

Press any key to continue...
```

Code used:

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

foreach (string p in ports)
{
    Console.WriteLine (p);
}
```

so my qestion is how do i find out which ports are acutally connected to my computer?

Comment: Is opening (and immediately closing) a SerialPort on each port and catching an exception to determine its availability not an option?

Comment: @yarik - not in this case. In my environment I'm seeing over 300 ports listed when no external adapters are plugged in.

Comment: I have the same question. Is it still doesn't work in 2019?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [mono source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.IO.Ports/SerialPort.cs), the `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` method just enumerates the **/dev/tty*** nodes:

```
string[] ttys = Directory.GetFiles("/dev/", "tty*");
...
foreach (string dev in ttys) {
    if (linux_style){
        if (dev.StartsWith("/dev/ttyS") || dev.StartsWith("/dev/ttyUSB") || dev.StartsWith("/dev/ttyACM"))
            serial_ports.Add (dev);
    } else {
        if (dev != "/dev/tty" && dev.StartsWith ("/dev/tty") && !dev.StartsWith ("/dev/ttyC"))
            serial_ports.Add (dev);
    }
}
```

So that's why you're getting all those **tty*** devices in the output.
But it's not so easy to determine which of them actually correspond to a (connected) serial port on your machine.

You can take a look on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125261/122374) answer. They're using an Unix **dmesg** command there followed by a **grep** to find out which devices are actually serial ports. They're even trying to figure out which of the serial port is connected on the other side too.

```
$dmesg | grep ttyS
[    0.872181] 00:06: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A 
[    0.892626] 00:07: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A 
[    0.915797] 0000:01:01.0: ttyS4 at I/O 0x9800 (irq = 19) is a ST16650V2 
[    0.936942] 0000:01:01.1: ttyS5 at I/O 0x9c00 (irq = 18) is a ST16650V2
```

Alternatively, you could parse the **/proc/tty/drivers** file, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701610/2846483).

There are a couple of [similar questions](https://superuser.com/questions/131044/how-do-i-know-which-dev-ttys-is-my-serial-port) about it. Perhaps you can find a solution that suits your needs best.

AFAIK there is no simple way to do this in mono directly, you have to go deeper.

---

### **UPDATE**

The reason why there is only one **/dev/ttyUSB0** item in case of a connected FTDI device seems to be pretty obvious.

In the same method, the `linux_style` flag value is determined by a simple look-up:

```
if (dev.StartsWith("/dev/ttyS") || dev.StartsWith("/dev/ttyUSB") || dev.StartsWith("/dev/ttyACM")) {
    linux_style = true;
    break;
}
```

So if there is a **ttyUSB*** device available, this flag will be set to `true`. This affects the device enumeration described above which returns a single item.