# Detect UART port names on BananaPi M3

Tags: python, uart, banana-pi

I'm trying to detect the UART port names for a BananaPi M3 device running a Raspbian so I can do a simple test to send and receive some data on it. I connected the RX and TX pins of the UART connector with a simple jumper but I cannot detect the actual name of the ports. The pins are described [here](http://www.bananapi.org/p/product.html) but I don't find exactly their names.

The tests I made so far without success:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1', 115200, timeout = 1)
    num = ser.write("test\n")
ser2 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS2', 115200, timeout = 1)
    data = ser2.read(100)
```

So, how exactly the UART port names can be detected.

Thank you

Comment: Did you have a look into the file system? `ls -l /dev/tty*` or so?

Comment: In addition to @glglgl I'd suggest using `ls -l /dev/ttyS*` in order to list serial ports only.

Comment: ls -l /dev/ttyS* outputs:                                                                             crw--w---- 1 root tty     249, 0 Dec 18 19:50 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 249, 1 Dec 18 20:12 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 249, 2 Dec 18 20:16 /dev/ttyS2              So, which is which?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all serial devices (ttyS, ttyUSB, ..) on Linux without opening them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530096/how-to-find-all-serial-devices-ttys-ttyusb-on-linux-without-opening-them)