# node.js path to serialport

Tags: node.js, path, serial-port

For this part of code for my node.js server

```js
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var port = new SerialPort("/dev/tty-usbserial1", {});
```

which use the https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport library.

How I can know this path to my serial port?

Comment: What your OS? Linux - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530096/how-to-find-all-serial-devices-ttys-ttyusb-on-linux-without-opening-them , on Windows you can look device manager and path will be like `COM3`

Answer (score 4):

I tried the previous answers in this question but they did not work in latest version of serial port (Sept 2020). We need to use `serialport.list()` function in promise approach like this:

#### import serialport package

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport')
```

#### Promise approach

```
SerialPort.list().then(ports => {
    ports.forEach(function(port) {
        console.log(port.path)
    })
})
```

I hope this will help you to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

To find the paths of available COM ports on the system, you can use the list method.

I'd advise omitting any that have an undefined manufacturer property as these normally seem to be things like built-in bluetooth etc.

Example:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport') 
SerialPort.list((err, ports) => {
    console.log(ports)                
})
```

Documentation:
https://node-serialport.github.io/node-serialport/SerialPort.html#.list

Answer (score 3):

As some things have changed in the last 3 years of JS I'd like to update totallyNotLizards' answer. As the documentations says in order to run this code you need to use **Promises**.

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport')
SerialPort.list().then(
  ports => ports.forEach(console.log),
  err => console.error(err)
)
```

Page where I grabbed this code from: https://serialport.io/docs/api-stream#serialportlist