# What would be the C++ equivalent of this bash script to list USB devices?

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, usb

Below Bash script lists serial port along with USB device friendly name. I'd like to do exact same thing but in C++ and without using dependency like libusb.

```
#!/bin/bash
for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && continue
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && continue
        echo "/dev/$devname "$ID_SERIAL""
    )
done
```

I have encountered [other C/C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12301542/207661) that use various APIs but none was able to get friendly name and /dev/ttyPort like above script. For example, output of above script is:

```
/dev/input/event13 Razer_Razer_Mamba_Tournament_Edition
/dev/input/event14 Razer_Razer_Mamba_Tournament_Edition
/dev/input/mouse0 Razer_Razer_Mamba_Tournament_Edition
/dev/input/event4 Razer_Razer_Mamba_Tournament_Edition
/dev/video0 Chicony_Electronics_Co._Ltd._Integrated_Camera_0001
/dev/input/event10 Chicony_Electronics_Co._Ltd._Integrated_Camera_0001
/dev/ttyACM0 3D_Robotics_PX4_FMU_v2.x_0
```

Comment: Can't you use a [system command](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) to call this script internally from C++?

Comment: Have you checked the `udevadm` sources for how it gets `ID_SERIAL`?